# How are related self-confidence and self-esteem?

Tags: personality, terminology

What is the difference between self-confidence and self-esteem?

Is it that self-confidence is more about feeling secure concerning one's own capacity to address problems, while self-esteem is more about a global appreciation of one-self?

Are they separate, and to what extent? Is it possible to have high self-esteem but low self-confidence, and low self-esteem but high-self-confidence?

I guess that normally the two are correlated

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this is an English Language question really rather than about psychology or neuroscience.

Esteem is about **respect and admiration**. See https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/esteem

Therefore, someone who has self-esteem respects themselves and admires their achievements.

So to expand on that, if you have self-esteem, that helps to have self-confidence which leads to a sense of security in an emotional sense.

Comment: So psychologists do not make a difference between "appreciate/respect oneself including one's achievements" and "being secure about one's capacity to tackle the problems that one might face"?

Comment: @starckman If you are looking at whether the person is secure or not, both are needed to be taken into account. You cannot have full emotional security without either.